# Why is 'a' in ('abc') True while 'a' in ['abc'] is False?

Tags: python

When using the interpreter, the expression `'a' in ('abc')` returns True, while `'a' in ['abc']` returns False. Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: `('abc')` isn't a tuple, it's just the string `'abc'`. To actually check membership in a tuple containing the string `'abc'`, use `a in ('abc',)`.

Comment: that's due to the dual use of parenthesis for expression precedence and for tuples, which lead to that strange syntax for single element tuples

Comment: The parentheses in `('abc')` are just for decoration, and also a potential source of confusion. It took me a while to get past this; I too thought that the parentheses indicated something special (c.f. square braces or curly braces, which do mean something special). In this usage, those parentheses have zero meaning. There is no difference between `xyz = (x, y, z)` and `xyz = x, y, z`. It is the presence of a comma that has special meaning (except in the case of an empty tuple, where `()` does have special meaning).

Comment: You can, of course, just type `'abc'`, `('abc')` and `['abc']` into the interpreter, and see what that thinks they are.

Answer (score 136):

`('abc')` is the same as `'abc'`. `'abc'` contains the substring `'a'`, hence `'a' in 'abc' == True`.

If you want the tuple instead, you need to write `('abc', )`.

`['abc']` is a list (containing a single element, the string `'abc'`). `'a'` is not a member of this list, so `'a' in ['abc'] == False`

Answer (score 49):

`('abc')` is not a tuple. I think you confused that with  tuple `('abc',)`.

Actually, `('abc')` is same as `'abc'`, an `array of characters` where `a` as character is in it, hence, the first lookup returns `True`:

```
>>> 'a' in 'abc'
True
```

On the other hand, `['abc']` is a list of string or a list of list of characters *(you can think of it as a 2-d matrix of characters `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`)* where `a`, as a single character, is not the member of the outer list. In fact, it is the first character of the inner list:

```
>>> 'a' in ['abc']
False

>>> 'a' in ['abc'][0]
True

>>> 'a' == ['abc'][0][0]
True
```

Comment: Can you please tell me and/or add reference about the meaning of this `'a' == ['abc'][0][0]`

Comment: 'a' == ['abc'][0][0]    "a" is in (list first elem > first char )

Comment: Or in other words, once the first `[0]` is applied, you're left with `'a' == 'abc'[0]` (it gives the first element of the list), then, after applying the second `[0]`, you're left with `'a' == 'a'`, which evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Ahmed `['abc'][0]` gives you `'abc'`. `'abc'[0]` gives you `'a'`.

Answer (score 3):

For `('abc')` you get 'a' in `('abc')` return true.

But for `['abc']` as it is a array list you get 'a' in `['abc']` return false.

**Example:**

*Input:* `('abc') == 'abc'`

*Output:* `True`

So if we call 'a' in ('abc') it is same as 'a' in 'abc' because ('abc') is not a tuple but 'abc' is a array of character where character 'a' is in index 0 of string 'abc'.

On the other hand ['abc'] is array list where 'abc' is a single string which is at index 0 of array ['abc'].

**Tupple Example:** *`x = ('abc', 'def', 'mnop')`*

**Array Example:** *`x = ['abc', 'def', 'mnop']`*

or

```
x = ('abc'), y = 'abc'
```

Here always `x == y`.

But in case of `'a' in ['abc']` =>

```
x = ['abc'], y = 'abc'
```

Here `x != y` but `x[0] == y`

Answer (score 2):

As others has mentioned, `('abc')` is not a tuple.  `'a'` is not a element of `['abc']`. The only element in that list is `'abc'`

```
x='abc' in ['abc']

print (x)

True #This will evaluate to true
```

This will also evaluate to true:

```
y = 'a' in ['a','b','c']

print (y)

True
```

Answer (score 0):

`('abc')` is equivalent to `'abc'`.

`'a' in ('abc')` is equivalent to `'a' in 'abc'`.

`'a' in ('abc', )` returns `False` as `'a' in ['abc']`.

`'a' in ['a', 'b', 'c']` returns `True` as `'a' in 'abc'`.